# wget command not working in cronjob

Tags: cron

here is my command :

```
wget -c -O /home/alireza/Desktop/1.mkv http://mysite.com/myfile
```

and here is my `/etc/crontab` file :

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

MAILTO=root
HOME=/
0 2 * * * root wget -c -O /home/alireza/Desktop/1.mkv http://mysite.com/myfile
```

I want to run my wget command on 2:00 AM by crontab and it never runs,I dont know whats the problem.
the command works fine on command line .
is there any problem to run wget command on crontab ?

UPDATE :: Im using centos 6.4

Comment: Try setting the task to run task every minute and check root's mailbox to see what happened.

Comment: try to redirect output of `wget` .eg `wget -c -O link  >/opt/wget.log 2>&1`

Comment: There is no problem running wget or any other command in cron. Check the output in root's mailbox. Maybe you need to set a proxy, or maybe the file is in a FUSE directory that's not accessible to root (e.g. if your home directory is encrypted with ecryptfs).